# How does multiple feature files work in Keras

Tags: keras

I was going through a Kaggle kernel, where train data was of different data types, so it consisted of separating out features for different types like:

```
input_cat = Input((len(a), ))
input_num = Input((len(num_feat), ))
input_words = Input((maxlen, ))

#More layers are added to the inputs
#x_cat, x_num, x_words are updated vars for the 3 inputs

x = concatenate([x_cat, x_num, x_words])
#some final layers added
predictions = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)

model = Model(inputs=[input_cat, input_num, input_words], outputs=predictions)
```

Later the model is used to fit training data like:

```
model.fit([X_train_cat, X_train_num, X_train_words], X_train_targe, #other params)
```

I get how the separated feature files are trained separately, and then their weights are concatenated, which are then used to pull out predictions.

I just wanted to get a bit intuition behind this or is it as simple as processing different types of feature differently and then combining them for a better model.

Thanks!